# Divide results from two subqueries with condition where

Tags: sql, postgresql

I d like to divide the results of two subqueries from same table but with different 
`where` condition in Postgres

```
select (a / b) as result from 
    (select sum(price) as sales from transactions where order_type = 'return') as a,
    (select sum(price) as sales from transactions where order_type = 'sale') as b
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Well, the question is how should the right solution look like? I found my own solution SELECT (b.return / a.sales) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT sum(price) AS sales FROM transactions WHERE order_type = 'sale')  a, 
        (SELECT SUM(price) as return FROM transactions WHERE order_type = 'return' ) b

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use aliases there, you could select the division itself, for instance, try this:

`select 
    (select sum(price) from transactions where order_type = 'return') /
    (select sum(price) from transactions where order_type = 'sale') 
 as result;`

In a hypothetical `transactions` table like this:

```
 price | order_type
-------+------------
     4 | return
     5 | sale
     6 | return
(3 rows)
```

that query would output this:

```
 result
--------
      2
(1 row)
```

since (4 + 6) / 5 = 2

HIH

Answer (score 0):

You code should be fine.  You can write it more colloquially as:

```
select ( sum(price) filter (where order_type = 'return') /
         sum(price) filter (where order_type = 'sale')
       ) as result
from transactions;
```

This only scans the `transactions` table once.

This does run the risk of a divide-by-zero error, if there are no sales.  If that is a possibility:

```
select ( sum(price) filter (where order_type = 'return') /
         nullif(sum(price) filter (where order_type = 'sale'), 0)
       ) as result
from transactions;
```